How to hide "grey smoke box" outside the simulation frames
I'm doing a smoke simulation using a quick effect in evee. Everything is fine within the frames of the simulation. But in the rest of the animation, the domain smoke cube is visible on render.
I think i should fix some shaders but no have idea what should i do.
Inside domain keyframes animation:

Outside keyframes:

It would be nice to get a shader tree to fix this, or any recommendations.

Why not simply keyframe the Density of the Principled Volume? Within the frame range of the simulation set it to the desired value, outside the range set it to 0.

That's where I stopped. Apparently there is no other option

Of course there is another option, you could animate the render visibility of the domain. Or just simulate the smoke over the complete animation time. But the last sentence of your question sounds as if you want a solution within the material shader.

Ok. Will answer myself.
The best way I've found is to reduce the density of the Principled Volume outside of the keyframes to zero.
